# Iterating an array on an @EnvironmentObject when the application closes on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui, macos-big-sur

I have an `@EnvironmentObject` that serves an array to my main view. it's declared as follow:

**my_app.swift**

```
@main
struct My_AppApp: App {    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(DataModel())
        }
    }
}
```

**ContentView.swift**

```
struct NoteItem: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    var text: String
    var date = Date()
    var changed: Bool = false
}

final class DataModel: ObservableObject {
    @AppStorage("mytestapp") public var notes: [NoteItem] = []
    init() {
        self.notes = self.notes.sorted(by: {
            $0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedDescending
        })
    }    
}
```

I call this from the different views in the ContentView.swift as:

```
struct AllText: View {
   @EnvironmentObject private var data: DataModel
}
```

I added to my_app.swift th ability to detect when the user closes the app so I can perform some action.

```
#if os(macOS)
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {        
        // trying to iterate on the struct within DataModel() here
        print("app closing")
    }
}
#endif


@main
struct My_AppApp: App {
    
    #if os(macOS)
        @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    #endif
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(DataModel())
        }
    }
}
```

And now, I'm trying to access the struct within `DataModel()` so I can check if each element has a changed set but no matter what I try, or how I declare the environmentObject I get a `segfault`, or errors such as `No ObservableObject of type DataModel found. A View.environmentObjectfor DataModel may be missing as an ancestor of this view.`

How can I access that DataModel and iterate thru it so I can perform an action when I close the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible approach - to inject data model on `ContentView` appear, like

```
#if os(macOS)
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var dataModel: DataModel?   // << here 

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {        
        print("app closing")

        // use self.dataModel? here
    }
}
#endif


@main
struct My_AppApp: App {
    
    #if os(macOS)
        @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    #endif
    
    private let dataModel = DataModel()    // << here !!

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(self.dataModel)    // << here !!
                .onAppear {
#if os(macOS)
                   appDelegate.dataModel = self.dataModel  // << here !!
#endif
                }
        }
    }
}
```